# Logging claims in Azure Identity Experience Framework

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am having difficulty logging claim exchanges between technical profiles. I have set up Application Insights as described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights) and this seems to work just fine - except that the traces provide me with no information about input and output claim values at various stages of a user journey. This is especially problematic when an error in the journey is caused by a missing claim.

Is there a way to record this information as part of the trace?

Comment: They are all in there. Look for the CLMS object.

Comment: Thank you again, @JasSuri. You know, I just don't see that CLMS object in there. I even pasted all the trace entries in to a text doc to search for it. Is there something else that needs to be configured in order to log that info?

Comment: Did you set  DeploymentMode="Development" and DeveloperMode="true"? in the app insights config in the Relying Party policy file?

Comment: Hi @christok are you still looking for any help on this?